# Godaddy and PowerDNS authoritative records configuration

Tags: linux, debugging, dns, centos

I have a domain name and I have decided to configure a DNS server which to redirects the queries to it. The problem is that when I try to add it to the godaddy console it reports that the TLD is invalid. I am using Powerdns running on a Centos 7 VM. I am not using Poweradmin, only PowerDNS and Mariadb. I have public IP on the VM, but apparently Godaddy doesn't work with IPs. This is the records table in my DB: 
MariaDB

```
[powerdns]> select * from records;

    +----+-----------+-------------------+------+---------------------------+-------+------+-------------+----------+-----------+------+
    | id | domain_id | name              | type | content                   | ttl   | prio | change_date | disabled | ordername | auth |
    +----+-----------+-------------------+------+---------------------------+-------+------+-------------+----------+-----------+------+
    |  1 |         1 | test.com          | SOA  | localhost none@null.com 1 | 86400 | NULL |        NULL |        0 | NULL      |    1 |
    |  2 |         1 | www.test.com      | A    | XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX           |   120 | NULL |        NULL |        0 | NULL      |    1 |
    |  3 |         1 | test.com          | A    | XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX           |   120 | NULL |        NULL |        0 | NULL      |    1 |
    |  4 |         1 | test.com          | NS   | ns1.test.com              | 86400 | NULL |        NULL |        0 | NULL      |    1 |
```

I have open port 53 and I am getting a correct answer from dig and nslookup if I try to get the information about my domain. Actually I am not sure if I really need an NS record and if yes, what should be the type. This is the output of the dig and nslookup commands:

```
-bash-4.2$ dig +short test.com XXX.XXX.XXX.DNS
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX


-bash-4.2$ nslookup test.com XXX.XXX.XXX.DNS
Server:         XXX.XXX.XXX.DNS
Address:        XXX.XXX.XXX.DNS#53

Name:   test.com
Address: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

where the XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is the IP of my web server and XXX.XXX.XXX.DNS is the IP of my VM running Powerdns

P.S. I have changed my domain name to test.com and masked the IP of my web server and my DNS server.

Answer (score 2):

if you want you custom DNS, you need create at least 2 dns host names:

1. login godaddy, and open dns panel(the url like: https://dcc.godaddy.com/manage/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME_HERE/dns )
2. click "host names", then click button "Add", then input hostname (like 'dns1') and your dns server's ip. and repeat (e.g, dns2 as hostname)
3. return domain dns panel, find "Nameservers" and click button "Change", select "Custom", and input dns1.YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME and dns2.YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME
4. dig YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME NS +trace, and make sure return the following lines:
   YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME    IN   NS   dns1.YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME
   YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME    IN   NS   dns2.YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME
5. configure your dns server.
   add zone YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME,and the NS record, and the dns1/dns2. A record.
6. test.
   dig www.YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME +trace
7. need 48 hours to expired on local dns server.